# How do I make the content of a string part of the code in Python?

Tags: python

In my program a string is edited, but the content of the string is also some Python code, which I want to add to the program. For example, I have a polynomial `px=x^2+x`, I want to add the line `pz=z^2+z` to the program, the content of this line of code can be obtained by `'pz=%s'%str(px).replace('x','z')`, but how do I make this string part of the code of my program?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the `exec()` function to execute it.

Comment: But maybe you should be using SymPi, or use the `ast` module to parse it.

Comment: There are ways of doing this, however it isn’t always a good idea. Can you provide some more context?